# System.IO.Exception with UWP FulltrustLauncher EXE

Tags: c#, uwp

System.IO.FileLoadException 0x80131040 C# UWP happens when my .exe is launched using             await 
FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync("Parameters")

This is weird because it works normal (NOT UWP), the FullTrustLauncher with DesktopBridge supposedly makes regular .exe's run in UWP but it appears not!

System.IO.FileLoadException 0x80131040 C# UWP happens when my .exe is launched using             await 
FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync("Parameters")

FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync("Parameters")

Comment: Check the manifest file, `<desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="yourexecutable.exe">`, is the name of the exe correct? and is the file "yourexecutable.exe" included in the package?

Comment: Could share a mini sample that could reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, that UWP apps need certain permission to open files, and can still not open every location. Doing it will lead to a System.IO Exception, which could be your problem, if you load a config file or so at the beginning. More info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions)

Comment: Yes but that absolutely is contradictory to "Full Trust"

Comment: @Sixjac Could share a mini sample that could reproduce the issue.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT please see link to sample below reproducing the issue, the sample is quite straight forward.                              
 https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VBoMFxGaUNdQrZ1eJXHVpxdzYjw7h0sj

Comment: I could run your project but the NBXplorer cmd window flash then closed, no `FileLoadException` throw in my side.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT thanks for the test, this is what i get with this sample   https://drive.google.com/open?id=120hXBw8gal69vnzEF3HXH3qLxEgfOF5u

Comment: Have you install [.Net core runtime](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download) component for operation system ?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT yes, and the NBXplorer console app runs fine when started standalone. Also anyway i believe VS2017 is still very buggy

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185818/discussion-between-nico-zhu-msft-and-sixjac).

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT are you still in the room?

Comment: @Sixjac Yes, I am online now.